# What is the use of 'did' attribute of string.xml in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I found some similar usages like followings:

```
<string name="add_button_tts_enabled" did="BODY_P1SS_P2SS">%1$s %2$s </string>
```

I just want to learn what 'did' attribute does here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be a custom attribute defined above. Check the complete code from start.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with example or any link for explaination .?